# Is there any way of combining the use of the 3D effect and freeform gradient fill on Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I am trying to use the 3D effect on a path. However, adding the effect does not change the path visually and returns the message:

> '3D and Materials' effect currently works only on some object types and cannot apply as multiple instances.

I assumed it was due to the path having the fill be a gradient, so I have tried the following:

- Turn it into Compound Path then use the 3D and Materials effect
- Change the fill into a solid color then use the 3D and Materials effect, followed by the freeform gradient fill (This worked up until the gradient)

Neither of the above worked. Is there a solution to this, such as changing the gradient to mesh under a mask? Or would this not work unless I use the 3D effect first, use the image trace tool to return it to vectors, then change those paths' fills?

Comment: I believe the 3D effect in newer releases of Illustrator all result in **raster** images. At a minimum one would need to use the Legacy 3D effect (without a gradient), then expand to adjust any fills. I am *guessing* here though since I don't use the latest AI release.